# Add column to huge table in Postgresql without downtime

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a very small table(about 1 mil rows) and I'm going to drop constraints and add new column. The query below is hang about 5 minutes, had to rollback.

```
BEGIN WORK;
LOCK TABLE usertable IN SHARE MODE;
ALTER TABLE usertable ALTER COLUMN email DROP NOT NULL;
COMMIT WORK;
```

Another approach suggested on the similar questions in the internet -

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl
(
  field1 int,
  field2 int,
  ...
);

INSERT INTO new_tbl(field1, field2, ...)
(
  SELECT FROM ... -- use your new logic here to insert the updated data
)

CREATE INDEX -- add your constraints and indexes to new_tbl

DROP TABLE tbl;

ALTER TABLE tbl_new RENAME tbl;
```

1. Create new table
2. Insert records from old table to new one (take less then a second)
3. Drop old table - this query hangs for about 5 minutes ~. Had to rollback. Does not work for me.
4. Renamed new created table to old one

Dropping old table simply hangs. However when I try to drop new created table with 1 million rows - it works instantly. Why dropping of old table takes so much time ?

```
SELECT blocked_locks.pid     AS blocked_pid,
         blocked_activity.usename  AS blocked_user,
         blocking_locks.pid     AS blocking_pid,
         blocking_activity.usename AS blocking_user,
         blocked_activity.query    AS blocked_statement,
         blocking_activity.query   AS blocking_statement
   FROM  pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocked_locks
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocked_activity  ON blocked_activity.pid = blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks         blocking_locks
        ON blocking_locks.locktype = blocked_locks.locktype
        AND blocking_locks.DATABASE IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.DATABASE
        AND blocking_locks.relation IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.relation
        AND blocking_locks.page IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.page
        AND blocking_locks.tuple IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.tuple
        AND blocking_locks.virtualxid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.virtualxid
        AND blocking_locks.transactionid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.transactionid
        AND blocking_locks.classid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.classid
        AND blocking_locks.objid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objid
        AND blocking_locks.objsubid IS NOT DISTINCT FROM blocked_locks.objsubid
        AND blocking_locks.pid != blocked_locks.pid
    JOIN pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity blocking_activity ON blocking_activity.pid = blocking_locks.pid
   WHERE NOT blocked_locks.granted;
```

I can see a lot of concurrent writes/reads which are waiting for my operation. Since I took lock on the table, I don't really think that the reason why I can't drop old table.

Just run vacuum on old table it did not help.

Why I can't drop old table why it takes so much time compared to dropping recently created table ?

Comment: An `alter table` will request a table lock anyway so you don't need to run `lock table` manually. The `drop not null` is just a meta data update and will only take a few milliseconds once the statement has obtained the exclusive lock. If you see that statement running for a long time, then your DDL is waiting for other transactions, not the other way round. Your second version won't change that. The `drop table` has to wait for the same lock. Did you check that you don't have any "idle in transaction" connections hanging around?

Comment: a DDL will always need an exclusive lock for some time period. Maybe the swap old<--> new table method will need a smaller service window, but you still need the exclusive access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to drop/rename table original table cause of FK of others tables. Once I dropoed it, approach with renaming table works great

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a lot of experience with PostgreSQL, but my guess is that it keeps a bit to signify when a `NULL`able column is `NULL` (as opposed to empty) and when that column is marked as `NOT NULL` it no longer needs that bit. So, when you change that attribute on a column the system needs to go through the whole table and rearrange the data, moving lots of bits around so that the rows are all correctly structured.

This is much different from a `DROP TABLE`, which merely needs to mark the disk space as no longer in use and perhaps update a few metadata values.

In short, they're very different actions, so of course they take different amounts of time.

Comment: The `drop not null` won't write anything to disk.It only updates the meta data about the table. Dropping a not null constraints will only take a few milliseconds. *Adding*  a not null constraint however would be something different as the database as to read **every** row to make sure that no value violates that.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. If this is the first item being set to allow `NULL` values then a bitmap needs to be added to every row on disk for which columns have `NULL` values.

Comment: I don't think so. Do you have any reference for that? I just tried it with a single column table with one column defined as `NOT NULL`  and dropping the `NOT NULL` constraint on a table with 10 million rows took 10ms

Comment: So why drop takes so much time which new created table if it merely mark the disk space as unused ?

Comment: @user12384512: the `drop not null` is fast. It's the waiting for the lock that takes so long

Comment: I'm droping whole table(DROP TABLE abc). What lock are you talking about ? I have no lock on this table

Comment: The PostGreSQL docs talk about the bitmap being present only when `HEAP_HASNULL` is true. How it goes about keeping that intact isn't clear though, so the rest was conjecture on my part. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/storage-page-layout.html